# Pentaho Calculator Step is not fetching correct results

Tags: sql, sql-server, pentaho

I am using Pentaho "Table Input step" to fetch the max created datetime in SQL Server Database then I am using "set variable step" to pass the variables into "Calculator Step". In calculator step I am framing a REST API with the condition. Please look into the below REST API which is giving the "created Datetime" result as "less than the created maxdate" whereas here in our API call the condition actually mentioned is "greater than the created maxdate". Please help me out with this issue.

"https://csscorp.service-now.com/api/now/table/em_event?sys_created_on%3Ejavascript:gs.dateGenerate(%272018-06-08 23:57:57%27)&&sysparm_display_value=true&sysparm_exclude_reference_link=true"

Comment: This doesn't look like an issue with Pentaho or SQL, but with your API instead. I would compare the query string you get from Pentaho with a sample one that is successful, you should be able to spot the difference. Also, the && looks like a parameter is missing. Maybe that's the spot where "greater than" should be.

Comment: I do not see the issue neither (except I do not catch the reason of a Set Variables. The point is: if you type the result of the `Preview` in your browser, do you get the expected answer ?

Comment: Thanks!In initial step of my transformation used the below Query in "Table input step" to fetch the max Date and max time"SELECT max(CONVERT(date, [sys_created_on])) as Lastdate, max(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CAST([sys_created_on] AS time))) as Lasttime FROM [Contelli-QA].[dbo].[SNOW_Event]" but while Previewing  this step I am getting the max date correctly whereas for maxtime ,it is not fetching the max time with repect to max Lastdate rather fetching the overall max time for that particular SNOW_Event table in Database.Eg:maxdatetime 2018-06-04 19:11:51.000 output for Lasttime=23:59:00 .help me

Comment: Thanks Cyrus,Because of the Previous max time issue ,the above framed API does not work .My requirement is to get all the records which is greater than maxDate and max time which Is mentioned in the api condition .Please find the below API:
"https://csscorp.service-now.com/api/now/table/em_event?sys_created_on%3Ejavascript:gs.dateGenerate(%272018-06-04 19:11:51%27)&sysparm_display_value=true&sysparm_exclude_reference_link=true".in the next run I need to get all records which is greater than this maxdatetime 2018-06-04 19:11:51 but in my case because of incorrect max time it is fetching wrong!

Comment: please some one check this issue why this is max time is not coming Properly and also please specify which sql Query I need to use so that the max time is correct with repect to max date.example : maxdatetime 2018-06-04 19:11:51 for me it is coming  Lasttime=23:59:00.help me out !